# Как преобразовать String параметр в нужный тип?

Tags: java

Есть метод, который принимает в качестве параметра имя класса, но как String. Как можно преобразовать этот String в нужный класс?

```
public void doStuff(String clazzName) {
     clazzName.doMore();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Class<?> clz = Class.forName(clazzName);
```

Например:

```
Class<?> clz = Class.forName("java.lang.Integer");
```